# SQL data issue : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am getting an error when trying to perform a query to get a date between a specific date range. The code was working fine before but today this error began to occur.

Through debugging i realize that the error only occurs when I keep the statement

```
 "WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(date_range) + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now + "' " +
                 "ORDER BY RCT.DATE DESC";
```

// Where date range is 150 days prior

Which when actually running the code produces

```
WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '23/05/2017 8:19:56 AM' AND '20/10/2017 8:19:56 AM
```

in my code. I have tried using the convert function but the error still persists.

SQL data error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Query:

```
SELECT 
       CST.CN AS [CUSTOMER#]
     , CST.ADR1 AS [ADDRESS]
     , CST.ADR2 AS [PARISH]
     , RCT.[IN]
     , RCT.IN2
     , RCT.DATE
     , RCT.ID
     , RCT.DISC
     , RCT.INTPD
     , RCT.AMOUNT2 AS[CASH / CA]
     , CST.CSTUD1 AS[ACCOUNT TYPE]
     , CST.NAME AS[L - NAME / COMPANY]
     , CST.FNAME AS[FIRST NAME]
     , CST.CITY
     , RCT.TYPE AS[PAYMENT TYPE]
     , RCV.BALANCE
     , RCT.TAXPD
     , RCT.AMOUNT 
FROM  
      (RCT INNER JOIN CST 
           ON RCT.CN = CST.CN
      ) 
           INNER JOIN RCV 
           ON (RCT.IN2 = RCV.IN2 AND(RCT.CN = RCV.CN)
              ) 
WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '23/05/2017 8:19:56 AM' AND '20/10/2017 8:19:56 AM' 
ORDER BY RCT.DATE DESC
```

The section of the code that deals with the date is RCT.DATE

---

Comment: I'd try putting the dates in YYYY-MM-DD format instead.

Comment: Yes , correct.  Date time store in this format

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention my actual code is  "WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(date_range) + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now + "' " +
                     "ORDER BY RCT.DATE DESC";  // Where date range is 150 days prior

Comment: So in this case how would i change the format?

Comment: Your issue is the time in your date. SQL dont understant AM or PM, the SQL Date must be in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:ML`. Remove AM and PM from your string.

Comment: What is the type of `RCT.DATE` column?

Answer (score 0):

The date format is incorrect. Try:

```
WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-23 08:19:56' AND '2017-10-20 08:19:56'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert.  Just set **DateFormat**

**Example**

```
Set DateFormat DMY

Select ...
WHERE RCT.DATE BETWEEN '23/05/2017 8:19:56 AM' AND '20/10/2017 8:19:56 AM'
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize your queries properly and you will never have to face this problem. So go do it as documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/). And if you must build tsql dynamically without parameters, then you need to use literals that can be interpreted correctly. For datetime valeus, read [this](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp)

And lastly - try searching the internet first since this question is asked **every day** somewhere.